# regexp_substr Finding two letter words

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I have a address field in Oracle from where I need o extract the State Code.

```
select  '111 BROADWAY ~ ST LOUIS, WA 58585' from dual   
union  
select  '111 BROADWAY ~ ST LOUIS, WA' from dual  
union  
select  '111 BROADWAY ~ ST LOUIS,58585 WA' from dual
```

Sometimes the state code `WA` is before `Postal Code` and some times after.
Also in some cases the `Postal code` is not present.

Need help to extract `WA` in all these cases.

Comment: Your title says something else: it says "finding **two letter** words". There may be two letter words in an address, that are not state codes (for example, Hilltop Av - Av is short for "Avenue", not a state code; or even the ST in your examples!). So: you want to find state codes? How do you distinguish them? Are they always the LAST two-letter word in an address? And does the address ALWAYS include a state code? (Otherwise you may pick up "Av" in my example, or ST in your examples,  and think it is a state code.)

Comment: The title is bit misleading. Yes the state code will be always here in the address. ST and WA are both state codes. So I am trying to see if I can extract the Two Letter words from end of the string. Thats my best chance

Comment: I can tell! So: Are you looking for the LAST two-letter word? And how do you define "word" - you may have something like 'London SQ1' - so you can't just look for two letters preceded and followed by a non-letter. Is the state code always preceded by **space**, and followed by **space** or the end of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can find the last substring consisting of exactly two letters, preceded by a space and followed by a space OR the end of the string:

```
select ...., 
       regexp_substr(address, '.*( ([[:alpha:]]{2})( |$))', 1, 1, null, 2) as state_code
...........
```

The regular expression looks for a single space followed by two letters followed by a space or the end of the string. Preceding that by `.*` guarantees that we find the LAST such occurrence. Then the REGEXP function returns just the two letters (the part of the pattern in the second pair of parentheses, counting from the left; that is the meaning of the last argument to `REGEXP_SUBSTR`).

Comment: Perfect. This helped a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Place United States State Abbreviation Code (2 Letters) in Pattern Parameter**

This is just a permutation of mathguy's answer.  Since we have defined and relatively short list of states codes, we could place the state codes (from usps website) in the pattern parameter and separate them using the alternation operator.

```
SCOTT@db>WITH tst AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          '111 BROADWAY ~ ST LOUIS, WA 58585' us_addrss
  4      FROM
  5          dual
  6      UNION ALL
  7      SELECT
  8          '111 BROADWAY ~ ST LOUIS, WA' us_addrss
  9      FROM
 10          dual
 11      UNION ALL
 12      SELECT
 13          '111 BROADWAY ~ ST LOUIS,58585 WA' us_addrss
 14      FROM
 15          dual
 16  ) SELECT
 17      regexp_substr(t.us_addrss,'( |,)(AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FM|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MH|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VI|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)( |$)' state_code
 18  ,1,1,'c',2)
 19    FROM
 20      tst t;
state_code
------
WA
WA
WA
```

Other 2 letter matches will not be included.  Also, my match parameter used, 'c', calls for the case to match.

This case requirement was not identified, but looks like it is consistent based on samples provided.

**More explanation:**

-My match pattern uses three character groupings and I reference the 2nd one in the sub-expression parameter.

-I check for a space or a comma preceding the two letter code.  From your example, you always had a space preceding the state code.

-I check for a space or the column ending after the state code.